# iCloud Photo Library doesn't load any photos (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

When I try to see some "old" photos on my iPhone (iOS 13.3), Photos just shows an exclamation mark icon:

[image]

This happens all the time. If a photo loads, it's a miracle.

Summary:

- Internet works
- All photos are uploaded successfully
- I have 40GB available on iCloud
- macOS Photos *and* iCloud.com work correctly, they let me download the originals
- I even upgraded my iPhone and restored from iCloud
- I have the latest iOS (13.3, same problem since the beginning, with 12.x)

Any solutions?

Comment: allowing ""Photos" to use cellular (**General** > **Photo** > **Mobile Data** for:), this might help you. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6986218

Comment: Wow. I never checked that because I'm *always* on 4G yet my photos are uploaded. I guess the upload is part of "Sync" and the download is controlled by **Settings > Photos > Mobile Data.** Months struggling because of this. Thank you.  I hate Apple for not giving _any_ reason why the download failed (it happens in Safari and the App Store)